# Etale Slice Theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, soft-question

**I found the Luna's Slice Theorem very Technical. It will be helpful if someone illustrates the  geometry involved in the theorem. Also why this theorem so useful?**

This is Luna's Slice theorem from a lecture note of Jean-Mac Drezet [Luna's Slice Theorem and applications- Lecture note by Jean Mac Drezet](http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~jean-marc.drezet/papers/Wykno.pdf) 
[image: Luna_Slice]
And this is the Version of Luna's theorem when the point x is smooth- 
[image]

Also I will use the opportunity to attract attention to one of another question where I asked the meaning of a topological slice of a point- [Slice of a point of a topological space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1025810/slice-at-a-point-of-a-topological-space)

**Is there any other resource to know more about Luna's Slice Theorem?**

Comment: Many moduli spaces in algebraic geometry are of the form $X/G$; the slice theorem is very useful to understand their local structure. See for instance [this paper](http://retro.seals.ch/digbib/view?pid=comahe-003:1996:71::415) by Y. Laszlo.

Comment: Think of the case where the action is free. Then the theorem says that $X$ is a $G$-torsor over $X/G$.

Comment: @abx could you please give the link to that paper again?! the link is broken.

Comment: [Link to Laszlo's paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02566426.pdf).